# How to find position of word in file?

Tags: python

for example I have file and word "test". file is partially binary but have string "test". How to find position of word ( index ) in file without load to memory this file ?

Comment: What do you mean without loading the file to memory? Do you mean without opening it? I don't know how that would be possible... You're asking the computer to tell you where something is without being able to see it.

Comment: Explain what you mean with "without load to memory this file?", because if you mean what you said, you probably don't know how computers work.

Comment: Your final constraint is rather paradoxical. How would you know what's in the file if you don't read it? If you want to avoid reading large files all into memory at once, you could try buffered reading, but you still have to read at least up through the first match. Be careful if the match ends up straddling the end of the buffer, too.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot find the position of a text within a file unless you open the file. It is like asking someone to read a newspaper without opening the eye.

To answer the first part of your question, it is relatively simple.

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print content.index('test')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [memory-mapped files](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) and [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

> Memory-mapped file objects behave like both strings and like file
>   objects. Unlike normal string objects, however, these are mutable. You
>   can use mmap objects in most places where strings are expected; **for
>   example, you can use the re module to search through a memory-mapped
>   file**. Since they’re mutable, you can change a single character by
>   doing obj[index] = 'a', or change a substring by assigning to a slice:
>   obj[i1:i2] = '...'. You can also read and write data starting at the
>   current file position, and seek() through the file to different
>   positions.

Example

```
import re
import mmap

f = open('path/filename', 'r+b')
mf = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
mf.seek(0) # reset file cursor
m = re.search('pattern', mf)
print m.start(), m.end()
mf.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open(file_dmp_path, 'rb') as file:
fsize = bsize = os.path.getsize(file_dmp_path)
word_len = len(SEARCH_WORD)
while True:
    p = file.read(bsize).find(SEARCH_WORD)
    if p > -1:
        pos_dec = file.tell() - (bsize - p)
        file.seek(pos_dec + word_len)
        bsize = fsize - file.tell()
    if file.tell() < fsize:
        seek = file.tell() - word_len + 1
        file.seek(seek)
    else:
        break
```