# How to capture the next string after match in Python

Tags: python, string

Suppose my text file contains a string `key` followed by different strings. How I can capture the next string and write it inside a file in Python.

```
if 'key' in open('Internet.txt').read():
    f=open("pathex","w")
    f.write("written")
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19063909/1559401)? Basically first you have to find the location of 'key' and from there do whatever you want. Can you maybe post your file so that we can see its structure? There might be an easier way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can read file line by line and if `key` was there write a `written` into destination file:

```
 f = open("pathex.txt" , "w")  
 with open('Internet.txt', 'r') as file_source:
    for line in file_source:
        if key in line:
            f.write("written")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the op wants to write the string that follows 'key'. If that is the case, could use line.split() to tokenize the line into a list, then find the position of 'key' in that list and grab the next list element.

```
f = open("pathex.txt" , "w")  
with open('Internet.txt', 'r') as file_source:
    for line in file_source:
        if key in line:
            tokens = line.split()
            keyidx = tokens.index(key)
            f.write(tokens[keyidx +1])

f.close()
```

and dont forget to close the output file when you're done, too.
f.close. The context manager (with statement) only closes the input file.

There might be a more concise way than the code I provided, but hey, I'm new too.

Comment: You dont know how `file_source` is , maybe splitting with space dosen't work

Comment: True. Without knowing the format of the input file, I was going for a more generic example. Split can do more than split on white space though. Op can modify as needed to meet the input file spec.