# How to "best" check if a string/word occurs in a csv file

Tags: python, file, csv, find

I want to check if a specific word (user-defined via input) occurs in a csv file. Now, I've come up with a code that does that but since I'm a beginner and don't want to adapt any "bad habits", I'm wondering if it is the fastest, easiest and shortest possibility. Any given improvements are appreciated. sa

This works (mostly, see below), but the whole thing with the "yes" variable makes me think that there has to be a better way to solve this.

```
def add(self, name):
    with open(filepath, "r+") as file:
        csvreader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
        csvwriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
        yes = False
        for line in csvreader:
            if name in line[0]:
                yes = True

        if yes:
            print("This ingredient has already been added")
        else:
            csvwriter.writerow([name])
```

It sometimes throws an "IndexError: list index out of range". I don not have any idea as to why because it only does that sometimes. Other times it works fine...

Comment: Very simple improvement; add a `break` after `yes = True`. No point continuing going through the file. Otherwise, the code looks pretty good to me. If you can't store the file in memory, you're not going to get faster.

Comment: The index error, though, is unusual. Presumably there is a blank line at the end of the file? You could use `if line and name in line[0]:`

Comment: Why are you only checking the first word of a line? And your code will fail on empty lines, so check for that first `if line and [...]`.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa it's not the first word, it's the first _value_. It could easily be a sentence or more.

Comment: @roganjosh Each line is split at `delimiter` into tokens, or words.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa each line is split at the delimeter, yes, but there's nothing to say that the first index refers to a single word. That's not how CSVs work. There could a full address stored in the first index, complete with the delimiter character within it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find position of word in file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980969/how-to-find-position-of-word-in-file)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa _and_ it's not a dupe of that. I think you misunderstand how CSVs actually work.

Comment: @roganjosh "CSVs actually work" by being a simple text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 improvements you could make:

1. After the value is found and you set the `found` flag to `True`, add a `break`; there's no point continuing to scan the file.
2. Your index error likely comes from a blank line. This will be *falsey* so we can add a check for that before trying to access by index. `if line and name in line[0]:`. This will not attempt the index if the first condition is not `True`.

In terms of being *falsey*, this refers to objects that will be considered `False` without actually being a Boolean. This includes `None` and empty sequences such as an empty string (`''`), an empty list (`[]`) etc. Empty sequences don't support indexing, even for the zeroth index, so that's why you get an error on a blank line.

With falsey items, we don't need a direct comparison (`==`) to `True` or `False`; indeed they would fail. But you *can* do boolean-type checks on them e.g. `if some_sequence:` or `if not some_sequence:`. Also, `and` checks conditions left-to-right and will stop as soon as it finds a *falsey* condition. In the case of `if line and...` it never gets to the point of trying to index `line` because it already knows the list is empty. Hence you never try to take the index of the empty list.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error. Could you please explain, what "falsey" means and what the "line" condition in the if statement does?

Comment: @Viggar added an explanation but I'm on a phone. Hopefully it's clear.

Comment: Thanks, it became clearer now. One thing I still don't get, though: The "line" in the if-statement, does it come from ME declaring it "line" in the line above ( in the "for line in ..." part). Or is it a python-internal "keyword"?

Comment: @Viggar it has no meaning at all in Python; it comes entirely from you calling your loop variable `line`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `csv` at all to find a word in a file:

```
def word_in_file(filename, name)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if name in line:
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: Except that this now scans the full lines of text. If the value would only appear in the first column, this will be slower.

Comment: @roganjosh I assume you did a benchmark. How do you know `if ... in ...` does not shortcircuit when it found the first occurance?

Comment: And in all the cases it _doesn't_ find the value, it scans the entire text

Comment: What if the CSV has 100 columns and you're only interested in the first column? That's 100 times more work for every single file, regardless of whether or not the word exists, minus the one line when `in` might short-circuit

Comment: Not to mention that if you are indeed only interested in the first column, this is now prone to false positives

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got to take roganjosh's side. I definitely want to check a csv file which is, for my purpose, should be way more comfortable than a simple text file, right?

Comment: I don't have any gripes, but in the OP you stated you want to find a word anywhere in the file, not only the first column, so I think using `csv` for this is huge overkill, and you said you wanted to avoid "bad habits". Complicating code is a "bad habit", imho.

Comment: @Viggar A CSV file **is** a simple text file.

Comment: No it isn't. It has a structure defined by double quotes and a delimiter.